# Python urlretrieve saving files with ' \r\n ' after the file extension

Tags: python

I have a quick script that downloads a files by iterating through a `.txt` file with URLs.  For example the `.txt` file would be full of URLs like `www.foo.com/foo/foo/foo.pdf`.

Here is the script:

```
URLS = open("urlfile.txt").readlines()

for url in URLS:
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    try:
        urlretrieve(url, filename)
        print "Successful download: %s" % filename
    except:
        print "Error downloading %s" % filename
```

After I had a folder with all of my files, I was trying to manipulate them with another script and noticed that after troubleshooting, they all have an extension of `\r\n`.  If I `ls` the folder in the terminal it appears as `example.pdf??`, and if I list them in a Python terminal it appears as `example.pdf\r\n`.

Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be happening due to the return character at the end of each line in your txt file.Try stripping return character

```
filename = url.rstrip().split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: That did it, thanks.  I'm just wondering now why it never behaved that way in other scripts that I use the same thing...